# How to add a parser to an AngularJS directive thet replaces the original element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create an AngularJS directive that replaces de original element and do some filtering on its parsing function.

This first example does exactly what I want, but the directive doesn't replace the original element:

http://plnkr.co/edit/H19sKtaQoHMkJak2PzkT

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('nondigit', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        if(!modelCtrl) return; 
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
            //filtering in here
        });
    }
    }
})
```

In this second example, when I change the directive to replace the element, the parsing function is not called anymore and the filtering stop working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/DqmKAYoA1NGQNYuN6fwX

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('nondigit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="nondigitModel"></div>',
        scope: {
            nondigitModel: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            if(!modelCtrl)  return;
            modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
                //filtering in here
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Anyone can tell what I'm doing wrong on the second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I found a way to implement the desired behavior. I ended using two directives, one to apply the filter on a parser function and the other one to replace the element.

**Filter directive:**

```
.directive('nondigitFilter', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        if(!modelCtrl) {
          return; 
        }
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
            //console.log('parser');
            if (inputValue == undefined) return ''

            var formatted = inputValue.replace(/\D/, '');
            if (formatted!=inputValue) {
              modelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatted);
              modelCtrl.$render();
            }         
             return formatted;         
        });
      }
    }
})
```

**Element replace directive:**

```
.directive('nondigit', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><input nondigit-filter type="text" ng-model="nondigitModel"></div>',
    scope: {
        nondigitModel: '=ngModel'
    }
  }
})
```

**Usage:**

```
<nondigit ng-model="val"></nondigit>
```

Here is the working plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UW9wCFFXYqzhzy0iqoar?p=preview